# Ettercap se cierra al iniciarlo

Tags: linux

el error es el siguiente

*ERROR : 1, Operación no permitida [/build/ettercap-TFupjX/ettercap-0.8.3/src/ec_network.c:source_init:183]    pcap_open_live: wlp4s0: You don't have permission to capture on that    device (socket: Operación no permitida)*

si lo ejecuto con sudo me da el siguiente error:**

[/build/ettercap-TFupjX/ettercap-0.8.3/src/ec_network.c:source_init:183]
bash: [/build/ettercap-TFupjX/ettercap-0.8.3/src/ec_network.c:source_init:183]: No existe el archivo o el directorio

he modificado etter.conf poniendo eluid y el gid a 0. Tambien he descomentado las lineas donde pone "if you use ip tables"

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta parece fuera de tema, ya que se relaciona más con la configuración particular de un tipo de [software](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ettercap). Saludos

Comment: En qué so lo estás utilizando? lo as instalado tú?

Comment: dice que no tienes permisos para crear el socket es tan simple como `sudo` :V

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el siguiente error ejecutandolo con sudo

Failed to create secure directory (/root/.config/pulse): Permiso denegado